# Cannot get attached property to trigger in Avalonia UI

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am trying to expose a property of a custom control I created using Avalonia UI. My plan was to allow this property to be bound to a ViewModel of a foreign control through xaml. But I can't seem to get the `Changed` event handler to trigger. I've modeled this off of Avalonia's documentation, but I still can't get it to work.

**Here is my custom control:**

```
public static readonly AttachedProperty<SessionTableEntry> SessionProperty =
    AvaloniaProperty.RegisterAttached<CommandHistoryControl, SessionTableEntry>("Session",
        typeof(CommandHistoryControl),
        null,
        false,
        BindingMode.TwoWay);

public static SessionTableEntry GetSession(AvaloniaObject o) {
    return o.GetValue(SessionProperty);
}

public static void SetSession(AvaloniaObject o, object param) {
    o.SetValue(SessionProperty, param);
}
```

Here is the xaml binding that should the "Session" property of the CommandHistoryControl to the "Session" property of the ViewModel associated with the parent control.

```
<ctrls:CommandHistoryControl
            Grid.Column="2"
            Name="History"
            Session="{Binding Session}"></ctrls:CommandHistoryControl>
```

Then I set the Session property in the ViewModel for the parent control nothing happens.

```
InteractiveSessionWindow window = new InteractiveSessionWindow() {
            DataContext = new InteractiveSessionViewModel()
        };

window.ViewModel.Session = session;
```

Edit: I figured out some more information. The AttachedProperty getter and setter fire correctly, but only if the DataContext is null. As soon as I set the DataContext to something, AttachedProperties stop working. Is that expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you cannot set a DataContext ViewModel object AND also get a handler for AttachedProperty changes. To address this, I use the same ViewModel object, but assign it to the control without using DataContext.

```cs
public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
```

I then bind things to $parent[x].ViewModel in the xaml.

```xml
<Label Content="{Binding $parent[2].ViewModel.SessionId}"/>
```

I'm not a big fan of the solution because every time my xaml changes, I have to update the indices of all of my bindings... but it's been 5 months and I haven't figured out a better way yet.